# How can I Get textcolors from controls and assign them to a variable for later use?

Tags: objective-c, uicolor

I've set colors for my controls in interface builder.

I need to dump these colors and assign them to variables.

I then want to use these variable for other controls.

Can someone point me at an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you programmatically access one of the color properties of your control, actually depends on the control itself, and the color you want. But here is an example using `UIButton` storing its `currentTitleColor` property (`UIColor`).

```
// accessing the currentTitleColor of button1
// and storing in button1CurrentTitleColor
UIColor *button1CurrentTitleColor = [button1 currentTitleColor];
// or UIColor *button1CurrentTitleColor = button1.currentTitleColor;
// then assigning to a second button
[button2 setCurrentTitleColor:button1CurrentTitleColor];
```

That said, unless you really need to reuse the color, you can shortcut it like so :

```
[button2 setCurrentTitleColor:button1.currentTitleColor];
```

You can find the list of properties for each control class in their respective documentation pages. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I'm not explained very well. I'm trying to add another style to my app and keep a copy of the colours. Not at run time. So I'd thought I'd need to output the colours to the debugger and re-use them. Does that make sense ? Can you help me further ?

Comment: you want to store a color in a file ?

Comment: sorry I don't get it. You want to serialize them ?